# SQL - Get Random sample but to include all transaction IDs that are the same

Tags: sql, random

I need to get a random sample of my sales dataset and have done that effectively using the cast, checksum and newID method.

However my dataset is a sales data table  which can have c.1-10 transaction IDs that are the same because one transaction can include multiple products, and my current method of random sampling doesn’t include all transaction IDs that are the same. E.g. it will only pull 1 row of transaction ID= 17381 instead of all 6 rows.

I want to create a random sample that includes all transaction IDs that are the same so I have complete information of a transaction in the sample.

How can I do this?

Comment: Randomly sample the TransactionIDs, then join on all of the associated product rows?

Comment: What DBMS are you asking this for? And can you show your query?

Answer (score 0):

The reference to `newid()` suggests SQL Server.  A typical method to get 10 ids would be something like this:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id in (select top (10) t2.id
               from (select distinct t2.id
                     from t t2
                    ) t2
               order by newid()
              );
```

Note:  This might not be the most efficient method.